# ASP.NET mail client error: Failure Sending mail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I had a working mail client in Visual Basic that sent email perfectly. Then one day it stopped working.  When I used VB's `try/catch` on my method the exception it threw was `Failure Sending Mail`.

This doesn't help of course, because it's incredibly general. I have no clue why the mail isn't being sent. I searched the web, as well as StackOverflow, but none of the solutions provided worked for me.

I've tried Aol and Gmail and I'm sure that all passwords and usernames are correct. Also the port is correct too. What could be the problem?

```
        Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    Try
        Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.aol.com")
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage()
        smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("Email", "Pass"
        smtpServer.Port = 587
        smtpServer.Host = "smtp.aol.com"
        smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        Mail.From = New MailAddress("Email")
        Mail.To.Add("Email")
        smtpServer.Send(Mail)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Is there an InnerException?

Comment: Ill post the code in a minute.

Comment: @SLaks, how can I tell if its an innerexception?

Comment: All exceptions have a propertY called InnerException

Comment: What's the property innerexception do?  how do I access it to see if its true or false?

Comment: Look at `Ex` in the debugger.